# AppSetting OpenNetCf for .NET CF 2.0

Tags: windows-mobile, opennetcf

I wish to use OpenNetCf. However, the device that I am using is on .NET CF 2.0. I tried using the Appsetting class to store configuration files however it spits an exception error that it needs newer version. How do i solve this?

(Upgrading to .NET 3.5 CF is not possible as of the moment.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild the SDF targeting 2.0.  A vast majority of the code is 2.0-compliant.  I think it's only in the networking stuff that we moved to 3.5-dependent coding using LINQ.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will look for the source code and compile it as suggested.